# Meteor app is printing [object Object] instead of values?

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

Attempting to learn Meteor. I went through the Discover Meteor book and am now trying to create a simple app myself, but I'm stuck just setting up some basic templates and routing. Rather than displaying the values of the object out, I'm getting [object Object] instead. I read in another question that this is the result of attempting to print an object instead of a string, but I thought that using {{temperature}} and {{outlook}} would return the values....

Feel like I'm missing something basic. Code is below:

layout.html:

```
   <template name="layout">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="main" class="row-fluid">
        {{yield}}
    </div>

 </template>
```

router.js:

```
    Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.route('forecastList', {path: '/'});
});
```

forecast_list.html:

```
<template name="forecastList">
<div class="forecast-container">
    <div class="row forecasts">
        {{#each forecasts}}
            {{> forecastItem}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

forecast_list.js:

```
var forecastData = [
    {
        temperature: '30',
        outlook: 'Today is forecasted to be sunny.'
    },
    {
        temperature: '75',
        outlook: 'Today is forecasted to be cloudy.'
    }
];
Template.forecastList.helpers({
    forecast: forecastData
});
```

forecast_item.html:

```
<template name="forecastItem">
    <div class="forecast">
        <div class="forecast-content">
            <h1>{{temperature}}</h1>
            <h2>{{outlook}}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Template.forecastList.helpers({
    forecasts: function(){
       return forecastData;
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried both, neither seems to work... hrm. I wonder if there's anyway I can better figure out what is going on.

Comment: ....I fixed it. It was a combination of your first solution as well as changing {{yield}} to {{>yield}} in the layout template.